# startActivityForResult is not working in Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am currently working with with Fragment. I want to  pick Image from gallery & display it onTo fragment class. But here startActivityForResult() is not working in Fragment.

My fragment class

```
Button loadimage=(Button) view.findViewById(R.id.loadButton);
    loadimage.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
             startActivityForResult(i, RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE);
        }
    });
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE && resultCode == RESULT_OK && null != data) {
        Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
        String[] filePathColumn = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };

        Cursor cursor = getActivity().getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,
                filePathColumn, null, null, null);
        cursor.moveToFirst();

        int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
        String picturePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
        cursor.close();
        imgview.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath));

    }

    }
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

In Activity class:

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode,resultCode,data);
}
```

In Fragment :

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){
    //  Handle activity result here  
}
```

start activity for result from fragment:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
```

Answer (score 6):

Override onActivityResult in your parent Fragment Activity

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
     super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```